# Why am I not getting a valid response from this REST API web service with Postman?

Tags: php, rest, api, postman

I have a API web URL which only accepts POST commands for searching it’s contents. I have authorized it with an API –KEY and an unique ID in the header tab of postman and put all the requires fields in the Body tab .

I am getting a response from the server saying that they got my request because I am getting a request_id back. But for some reason I am getting the response status as “ERROR”. I am not sure what’s going on . What could be the reason that’s causing the server to accept my request, but not able to reply back ? I been trying to get any response from this server that makes sense for the past 6 hours.
Here are some of the data fields I am sending the server in the Body.

```
{
    "device_id_type": "aaid",
    "device_id": "BAC9BA51-4C51-45C8-8091-3F6890A21A70",
    "app_version": "1.1",
    "country": "US",
    "q": "hello",
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 20,
    "locale": "en_US",
    "tz_offset": -5,
    "gender": "m",
    "age": "21-24",
    "geo": "40.7506, 73.9935"
}
```

Response from the server:

```
{
    "request_id": "ec78cd56c7da4c078d8ee5d456c52c71",
    "status": "ERROR",
    "data": {
        "error": {
            "code": 500,
            "message": "An unexpected error has occured"
        }
    }
}
```

[Response from server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAXsj.jpg)

[Code Snippet from postman](https://imgur.com/zfdzRTW/%22Code%20Snippet%22)

Comment: i don't think this question related to the android.

Comment: Thanks for your response Abhishek. The API service I am trying to hit is actually related to an android app SDK. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: but its clearly looks like API issue.. first you need to be sure its wroking with postman or not if it works with postman and not with android then we can say its android related question. better to ask developer who designed the api.

Comment: Who did create the API? You should ask this question to the developer who created the API